# Advice and usage of CRTP and Policy Based Design as an abstract data type for design of game engine component's base wrapper

Tags: c++, api, graphics, crtp

This is more of a code design question that a programming one, and I would like to open an input discussion on this.

Basically I am looking into writing my first real serious game <strike>engine</strike> framework as a fun project and I am thinking of writing a common interface to help simplify the graphics command routines(e.g Create...Buffer, Bind etc) that each wrapped API (Direct3D, OpenGL, eventually Mantle) have to implement.

After reading Dave Eberly's 3D Game Engine Design, his code uses the dynamic polymorphism and that means there will be a lookup cost associated with the vtable in runtime. So my main question here is this: would it be better that I take things one step further and implement the graphics API interface with CRTP and have the renderer class act as a Policy-Based class that would allow me to have the flexibility to choose and select which API I would like to use during compile time via the usage of preprocessing macros?

In this case, is favouring static-polymorphism better than dynamic-polymorphism?

Comment: The problem with the CRTP and static polymorphism is that it provides dynamic binding, but does not provide the polymorphic behavior. That is, even if the CRTP could solve calls from base classes pointers/references to derived classes, that references cannot be treated in a hommogeneus way, because each base class pointer/reference has its own type. So the tipical game engine polymorphic list of scene objects its impossible using CRTP directly. However, I think you could achieve this using an heterogeneous container or something like `boost::any`.

Comment: Hmm the boost::any bit looks interesting, I'll look into that. However, I am not looking into using CRTP for scene objects. Rather I am looking into using it for the as the interface (for a lack of better term) contract that the API implementation to follow and keep a consistent behavior for the code residing at the lower level for the framework. Something like this:

Comment: I understand what you mean by the polymorphic behavior, but I was thinking since I am going to encapsulate off the lower layer from the framework user anyway. Would favoring static-polymorphism be the beneficial routine? Which kind of beg the question, how much optimization does the compiler do for the virtual table look up these days?

Comment: Modern compilers try to elide the virtual function indirection (and other related stuff, like function pointers calls) using profiling aided optimizations, translating function pointers dereferencing into if else tables to take advantage of the branch predictor. On the other hand, the main problem of virtual functions (and the most powerful advantage of CRTP-based polymorphism) is that they cannot be inlined easily. But as I said, if you provide good profiling data to your compiler, it could do inline-like optimizations just as JITs do.